# Error Plotting a 3 phase Sine Curve using Matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

[image]

Recently I tried to plot a 3 phase AC. Everything works fine until I checked my Peak of sine is not coming at 90, ie sin(90)!=1.

I was not able too find any phase shift errors etc

```
time = np.linspace(0, 4*np.pi, 200)

plt.plot(time, np.sin(time) , label='sin(x)')
plt.plot(time, np.sin(time - 2*(np.pi)/3) , label='sin(x+pi/3)')
# (- 2pi) becasue +pi was not showing expected output
plt.plot(time, np.sin(time + 2*(np.pi)/3) , label='sin(x+2pi3)')

plt.axhline(y=0, color='k')
plt.axvline(x=np.sin(np.pi/2))
plt.legend(loc = 'lower right')
```

expected is a correct sine output

Comment: problem is when u try to plot axvline(x=np.sin(np.pi/2)) at curve peak is not achieved

Comment: iam new , idk how to post,  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268469/why-cant-users-with-less-than-10-reputation-points-add-images-while-asking-ques

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing a fundamental mistake. You need to just pass the value of `x=np.pi/2` to `plt.axvline`. You are passing `x=np.sin(np.pi/2))` which evaluates to `x=1`, that's why you see a vertical line at `x=1`

```
plt.axvline(x=np.pi/2.)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks , i didnt noticed it